# Installing a floating stone wall around the TV

Tags: tile, stone, frame

I just wanted to add some stone veneer tiles around the TV.

The tv is 55" (32x5" x 57")

The frame behind the TV would extend 16" on each side.

By frame, I mean stone tiles. [These are the tiles](https://www.rona.ca/en/product/avenzo-iceland-crystal-6-in-x-24-in-white-and-grey-natural-stone-wall-panels-6-box-ch-icelndcr-09465078)

I can create a 2x4 frame and install cement board on it which will hold the stone tiles.

My dilemma is that I do not want to extend the stone tiles all the way to the floor. Can I attach some 2x4 on the wall horizontally (screwed into the studs behind the drywall ) install cement board on it and then add tiles?

OR

Build a proper frame that sits on the floor, screwed to the drywall with cement board and stone tile? With this approach I can install a piece of drywall in the bottom to hide the bottom part of the frame.

By frame, I mean stone tiles. s on the floor, screwed to the drywall with cement board and stone tile? With this approach, I can install a piece of drywall in the bottom to hide the bottom part of the frame.

In both cases, stone tiles will only be attached to the cement board and won't be sitting on the floor. What kind of issues I can run into with this approach?

Comment: It's not clear what you are concerned about.  What assumptions are you making that you think are restricting you from doing what you want?  You can build a stone facade around the TV.    You maybe are suggesting that the stone veneer should be *supported* by the floor?  Is that your assumption?  (It's wrong).  Otherwise it's not clear what you mean by "Can I ...." because why do you think you maybe cannot?

Comment: @jay613 Hi, yes, that's exactly is my concern. That tiles may get heavy and need to be supported by the floor. So do you think I should put some horizontal 2x4 or just put cement board over the drywall and screw in to the studs? Thanks

Comment: You want to build a miniature wall with a top plate, bottom plate, and window cut into it. Screw the horizontal pieces into the stud framing in the wall behind your pop-out. To accomplish that, use a spade bit to cut a 2" deep hole in the edge of the 2x4s so that you can install a few deck ledger screws ithrough to the back wall's studs.

Answer (score 2):

Wall tiles are not supported by the floor or by the tile beneath.  They are glued to the wall with tile adhesive, and gaps in between that are later filled with grout.  The adhesive does all the work.

You do not need to build a wood frame to support your tiles.  If your tiles do not extend all the way to the floor, ceiling, or adjacent walls, you will have to create an edge for them, but how you do that is entirely a matter of appearance.  If you are framing a TV you might want your tiles to be quite deep.  Maybe then you'll build a 2x4 frame all around the TV, place drywall over that, and tile over that so it will be a couple of inches proud of the surrounding wall.   Or maybe you think that's a terrible idea.  It's up to you.  Some tiles have available custom edge strips and corners.  You can buy generic contrasting edge and corner tiles to go with anything. They can also be made of metal, resin, wood, etc.  For the stone veneer you chose around a (black) TV you might choose a black acrylic edging strip.  Or you might thing that's ugly .. I'm not a decorator.

Whether you glue the tiles directly to existing drywall, or cover the drywall with cement board, or replace the drywall with cement board, depends on the environment, the tile, the adhesive and more.  If the room is not humid and does not fluctuate too much in temperature or humidity and if the drywall was put up properly with a view to tiling ... you can just tile over it.

Answer (score 0):

The frame does not have to go to the floor.  It just has to be constructed strong in the first place.  I have almost the same situation with really heavy unpolished marble tiles.  The support frame cantilevers over the fireplace with glass walls.  It has been 6 years and it hasnt dropped.

[image]

Comment: Yes. This is what I'm trying to achieve without the fireplace. I will add tv console later but that won't adding any support to the frame. How did you build the frame for your tv wall? Thanks.